# How do I set a delay on a file upload in React?

Tags: reactjs, upload, setinterval

I want to batch my records for uploading so I don't create server issues. I would like to be able to push 10 records at a time, every five seconds, just to prove the concept for now. I've put setInterval functions all over my code but can't get it to run at the right time. I've been at this for days but can't figure it out.

```
chunkData(data) {
    const maxRecords = 10;
    const loops = (data.length % maxRecords > 0) ? Math.floor(data.length / maxRecords) + 1 : data.length / maxRecords;
    //console.log('data: ', data);
    //console.log('loops: ', loops);

    //setInterval(() => {
        for (let loop = 0; loop < loops; loop++) {
        console.log('loop: ', loop);
        let start = loop * maxRecords;
        //setInterval(() => {
          for (let batch = start; batch < start + maxRecords; batch++) {
            // the line below will become the upload function once I get this to work
            if (data[batch] !== undefined) console.log('data[batch]: ', data[batch]);
          }
          //start = start + 10;
        //}, 5000);
      }
    //}, 5000);
  }
```

I'm certain it's a simple tweak I need but I'm clueless as to how to make it happen right now. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The bigger problem you'll have to figure out is that a client-side change will not help in this case. If you're trying to help your server this way, what happens when there is more than 1 concurrent user uploading? 2? 3? 100? 1000? This solution isn't scalable. You'll eventually (or very quickly) have to make sure your server is robust enough to handle upload traffic.

As for your specific code. Your problem is that you're using *setInterval* inside a *for-loop* but use the same value. Remember, uploading (or any XHR/fetch request) is an asynchronous action. Right now, you're setting the intervals to run at basically the same time.

To get actual intervals between uploads, you'd need something like this:

```js
for (let loop = 0; loop < loops; loop++) {
        console.log('loop: ', loop);
        let start = loop * maxRecords;
        
          for (let i=1, batch = start; batch < start + maxRecords; i++, batch++) {
            // the line below will become the upload function once I get this to work
            if (data[batch] !== undefined) {
              
              setInterval(() => {
                //make upload request here
              }, (loop + 1) * i * 5000);
            }
          }                  
      }
```

*I'm not sure what your "start" variable is supposed to be.*

In any case, this code is really error prone and fragile. I really advise reconsidering your approach and look into fixing your server side.

If you still wish to go with this client-side hack and even if not, and you're looking for a more stable client-side solution. I advise to go with [react-uploady](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady). It takes care of the uploads for you and all the edge cases that come with managing uploads in React.

You can even do your intervals easily:

```js
import ChunkedUploady, { useChunkStartListener } from "@rpldy/chunked-uploady";
import UploadButton from "@rpldy/upload-button";

const CHUNK_SIZE = 1e+6;

const UploadButtonDelayedChunks = () => {
    useChunkStartListener(() => new Promise((resolve) => {
        //delays chunk upload by 5 seconds
        setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
    }));
    
    return <UploadButton/>;
};


export const ChunkedExample = () => {
    return (
      <ChunkedUploady
        destination={{ url: "https://my-server/upload" }}        
        chunkSize={CHUNK_SIZE}>
        <UploadButtonDelayedChunks/>
      </ChunkedUploady>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a comprehensive answer. I will check it properly on Monday but I truly appreciate it. React-uploady sounds exactly what I'm looking for although I might just tinker with the code to understand what I was doing wrong anyway.